# Python Matplotlib: How to disable Constrained Layout but keep the axes position?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created a (3,2) subplots and forced them in `constrained_layout=True`.
Then I wanted to disable the constrained_layout with `.set_constrained_layout(False)` due to performance issues, but I 'd like to keep the axes positions.

I tried to get the positions in constrained layout state, and then apply these positions to the axes after setting `constrained_layout` to `False`, following [these instructions](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#constrained-layout-guide), but it doesn't work.

With the code below, I expected to obtain the following figure, but I ended up with the one below it.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,2,constrained_layout =True)

mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.showMaximized()
fig.canvas.draw()

bounds = [ex.get_position().bounds for ex in fig.axes]

fig.set_constrained_layout(False)

for i in range(len(fig.axes)):
    fig.axes[i].set_position(bounds[i])

fig.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it wrong to adjust the vertical and horizontal in the subplot?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,2)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.3)
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve, because there will be missing some configuration of the border spaces and, also, the window would not be automatically changed when maximized. What I really wanted was to keep the configuration from the `constrained_layout ` after disabling it.

Comment: One curious thing is: if I run the code in interactive mode (`plt.ion()`) until the line `fig.canvas.draw()` and run the rest of the code after the figure is drawn, it keeps the `constrained_layout` configuration even after disabling it. I ended up using this approach.